# Auth0 Create User Script Giving Me an Error of "mysql is not a function"

Tags: mysql, database, auth0

Here is my code for the create user script for using custom database in Auth0

```
function create(user, callback) {
  const mysql = require('mysql');
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

  const connection = mysql({
    host: configuration.host,
    user: configuration.user,
    password: configuration.password,
    database: configuration.database
  });

  connection.connect();

  const query = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';

  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    const insert = {
      password: hash,
      email: user.email
    };

    connection.query(query, insert, function(err, results) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      if (results.length === 0) return callback();
      callback(null);
    });
  });
}
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwScp.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems `createConnection` has not been called. So basically it should be something like this:

```
function create(user, callback) {
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: configuration.host,
      user: configuration.user,
      password: configuration.password,
      database: configuration.database
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) return callback(err);

        var query = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return callback(err);

            var values = {
              password: hash,
              email: user.email
            };

            connection.query(query, values, function (err, result) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                if (result.length === 0) return callback();
                callback(null);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: hmm I tried doing that and then this new error came up : "[Error] ECONNREFUSED - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306"

Any idea on how to fix? Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: It seems you are trying to connect to a database which is hosted on your local machine? which is in 127.0.0.1:3306. Correct?
In such a case Auth0 can not access your database. First you have to make it accessible to Auth0.